# C# to ASP.NET MVC FileStream Crossover

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have written code in C# and printed results to the terminal to confirm it is working. I am currently in the process of transferring some of the code over to an MVC 4 Controller and I have been able to successively merge most of it but I am having issues with one part.

I wish to read a database file (database.dat) and later on I wish to write to the same file.

In my controller I have:

> using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("database.dat"))
>                    database = (List)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

and

> using (Stream stream = File.Open("database.dat", FileMode.Create))
>                    formatter.Serialize(stream, database);

In both cases 'File' in File.OpenRead and File.Open is underlined and I receive the error:

> 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File(byte[], string)' is a 'method', which
>   is not valid in the given context ..."

Is there way I can achieve the same result in MVC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to add the fully-qualified name if you want to use the `File` class in `System.IO` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx). So something like this should work:

```
using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("database.dat")){
    database = (List)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Comment: @BASmith to clarify: There is a File method in the MVC controller  that's why you get an error regarding System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File, so you need to provide the full name of System.IO.File to get the regular File static class.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, quite a trivial thing that I probably should have seen myself but sometimes simply answers can be hard to see.

Unfortunately fixing that problem has revealed another though, it doesn't like the "Deserialize(stream)" and is telling me "SerializationException was unhandled by user code"

Comment: Nevermind with that previous comment, it's due to the fact that I was trying to force feed it my database.dat from a previous build, and the versions did not match. Recompiling it to make it's own database.dat should fix this.